# Enabling Xbox One Controls with UWP APP made with Unity

Tags: unity

I am creating a UWP game for PC it uses the mouse as the only form of navigation;I am using the latest version of Unity to make this UWP game. The question is regarding what happens when the UWP is running on the original Xbox One (which is software compatible with later xbox one models).How is the Xbox One mouse mode enabled in C Sharp in Unity in a UWP app? What is the Xbox one controls that are mapped from a PC mouse? I have tried all sorts of things but I can't get the xbox one controller to work as a mouse like controller.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. You say that your game is for PC but then talk about running it on the Xbox One. Are you running your game on Xbox One, or do you have an Xbox One controller connected to your PC?

Comment: I am making the game in unity on a PC-you can run the same UWP on PC,xbox one (also windows phone and holo lens but that is irrelevant). Running on an xbox one. Not an xbox controller interfaced to a PC.

Comment: Yes, you can run UWP on multiple platforms, but the question is a little confusing because you specifically say the game is "for PC". It might have been clearer if you said "for PC and Xbox One". Have you tried setting up custom controls for the Xbox One controller? That seems like a better solution than trying to treat the controller like a mouse.

Comment: It is just a guess but I think the "new" Unity input system handles input independently from the platform. I.e. if the system has a way to work with an input device and your game handles it, it will work. So you deal only with input actions (that have multiple physical bindings), and it is up to Unity and the system to decide what binding exist on the system. But again, it is just a guess.